# How to uninstall zsh

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

Is there anyway to uninstall zsh? I wasn't able to upgrade it so I want to uninstall it then install it using brew.

Comment: You are going to need to give a certain amount of detail about the environment you are working in. And you should specfiy that you mean take zsh off the system and not, change my default shell away from zsh (or the other way 'round).

Comment: @MaQleod: This is OS X, since the OP mentions using Homebrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to uninstall it. Since you're using Homebrew, you can simply make sure that Homebrew's `bin` directory is before anything else in your `$PATH`. For instance, put this in your `.bashrc` or similar:

```
PATH=$HOME/.homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I couldn't find .bashrc anywhere!! my path is getting messy, echo $PATH gave me: /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bin:/Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/Users/Home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/Users/Home/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: @Ans: If you can't find it, then simply create it. And the PATH messiness isn't bad.

Comment: Thanks Mark. but if I have to create it.. where did all that paths come from?!

Comment: You don't have to create the PATH. There's going to be some stuff automatically in there. You might have to create the `.bashrc` file is what I was getting at.

Comment: What about all the other paths, where are they? and can I change them?

Comment: The other paths are where some executables are located at. You shouldn't change them, otherwise you might not be able to access some commands (the normal way, anyways.)